# Prove that the homomorphism $f∶G \rightarrow Sym(G)$ given by $f(g) = f_g$ is an injective function.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $S=G.$ Recall that $g\cdot x∶=gx$ for $g \in G$ and $x \in S$ is an action of $G$ on $S.$
We defined the function already in class fyi.
We were also given this bit of information :  Recall that $Sym(S)$ = {σ ∶ σ∶ S → S is a bijection} is a group under composition and that the identity element in $Sym(G)$ is the identity function $idS$ that sends $x$ to $x$ and what is the value of $fg(eG)?$

The only thing I can think of to use is if you have function that is a homomorphism of groups $G \rightarrow H$ then you can show it is injective by showing if $f(a)=e_H$ this implies that $a=e_G$.

Comment: That's correct. You have to find all the $g\in G$ such that $f(g)=\text{id}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you came across is known as [the Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem) or a variant of. However there's something wrong with the details you wrote. For example $f(g)=fg$ formula doesn't make any sense. I suspect that you meant $f(g)=f_g$ and this is just a notation issue.

So here's how it works. If $g\in G$ then we can define $f_g:G\to G$ such that $f_g(x)=gx$. First thing you need to prove is that this is a bijection, i.e. $f_g\in Sym(G)$. And this follows because the inverse of $f_g$ is $f_{g^{-1}}$.

Next we define the function $F:G\to Sym(G)$ by $F(g)=f_g$. First we need to show that this is a group homomorphism, i.e. $F(gh)=F(g)\circ F(h)$. Once we do this we check that it is injective by calculating the kernel
$$\ker F=\{g\in G\ |\ F(g)=id\}=F^{-1}(\{id\})$$

where $id(x)=x$ is the neutral element of $Sym(G)$.

So let's do that. Assume that $F(g)=id$ for some $g\in G$. This means that $f_g=id$ and so for any $x\in G$ we have $f_g(x)=id(x)$ which by definition means $gx=x$. By applying $x^{-1}$ on the right to both sides we conclude that $g=e$. Therefore $\ker(F)=\{e\}$ is trivial which means $F$ is injective (by the well known property of homomorphisms).

Comment: Yes sorry I meant $f_g$ I will correct that.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

$S=G$

$(g,x) \mapsto gx$ is action of $G$ on $S$,

For fixed $g\in G$, $g$ permutes elements of $S$ by above action which can be identify as element $\pi_g \in \text{Sym}(S)$.

This induces homomorphism  $f: G \to \text{Sym}(S)$ defined as $g \mapsto \pi_g$ with $K=\text{Ker}(f)$.

Now, $g \in K$  $iff$  $g$ fixes every element of $S$ by above action.

And the only such element is $e \in G$.

Answer (score 0):

$f_g=f_h\Rightarrow f_g(e)=f_h(e)\Rightarrow  ge=he\Rightarrow g=h$, so $f$ is injective (irrespective of $f$ being a homomorphism).